# How does the process of protein denaturatation work?

Tags: temperature, physical-chemistry

I know it's the proteins that somehow change their properties at some temparature.

But what kind of change, in terms of molecule-level structure?

Comment: protein folding is biophysics, which is a separate department at many universities.  Isn't biophysics ok here?

Comment: @jinawee I would think the biologic effects of the changes are irrelevant in regards to the question, as are the chemical effects too - what remains is physics.

Comment: @jinawee http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4403/

Comment: Let's see what others think. But I guess it could be more specific, like: _What is the physical process of denaturatation?_

Comment: This is related to unfolding of structures of proteins... This is certainly chemistry... In fact I remember seeing a type of this question in my chem book..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denaturation_(biochemistry)#How_denaturation_occurs_at_levels_of_protein_structure

Comment: @jinawee Ok, makes sense, I'll change to that title!

Comment: @Awesome Just for future reference--rather than input on this question--it is possible for questions to be on-topic on more than one Stack Exchange site. In particular there are substantial areas of overlap between physics and both chemistry and astronomy. In those the poster can put it where (s)he likes, but for new posters you might appraise them of the existence of the other site.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the egg-white (just another protein structure) is made of long chains of amino acids. They're held in shape by weak bonds. When you heat the structure, the energy you put in, is enough to break those bonds, thereby destroy the structure. This process [has a name for it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denaturation_%28biochemistry%29#Common_examples).

Once the temperature is high enough, new covalent bonds can form between the amino acids, and the amino acids in some other protein and they become entangled into a much more complicated structure, which is completely different from the real one. As you cool, you get this finished structure as cooked egg...

Comment: Ah, thanks, now I start to see how it's chemistry, I saw it as related to a phase change... I'll ask for migrating it - Oh, I'll better take out of the title the explicit "physical" before